# Rotating contour labels on Canvec layer

Tags: qgis, elevation, contour

I have created a QGIS map using CANVEC layers including elevation features. The resulting contour lines look good, but the elevation labels are not aligned with the contour lines (see screenshot below). I don't see anything in the layer settings to address this problem.

Help?

[image: clip of QGIS map showing CANVEC contours]

Comment: What is a CANVEC layer? Can you describe a bit more in detail how you created the labels?

Comment: Topographic OpenData of Canada - CanVec Series https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/8ba2aa2a-7bb9-4448-b4d7-f164409fe056

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `render` box is ticked beside the canvas `rotation`

[image]